# Обновлять чат только если это требуется

Tags: javascript, php, ajax, chat

Короче братцы нужна хелпа по чату, объясняю на данный момент на сайте есть чат - "самописный без подключения сторонних ресурсов", есть база отправленных сообщений MySql, на данный момент чат обновляется каждые 0.5 секунд вне зависимости от того есть ли новое сообщение или нет. Из этой проблемы выходят еще две. ибо сам скрипт чата фигурирует на каждой странице сайта + зайдя в нетворк можно увидеть прекрасный спам запросами на показ новых сообщений "которых может и не быть".

Задача - обновлять чат только если какой-либо из пользователей сайта отправил в него сообщение.

Вот готовые скрипты на ajax с

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {
    var button = $("#chatsubmit");
    button.click(function() {
        var text = $("#chatmessange").val();
        if (text == "") {
            alert("введите текст");
        } else {
            $.ajax({
                url: "/catr/get",
                type: "POST",
                data: ({
                    text: text
                }),
                success: function() {
                    $("#chatmessange").val("");
                }
            });
        }
    });
    window.setInterval(function() {
        $.ajax({
            url: "/catr/show",
            success: function(data) {
                $("#chatblock").html(data);
            }
        });
    }, 1000);
});
```

Если реализовать такую задачу нереально, можете привести свои примеры юзая сторонние ресурсы.

Comment: вам определенно нужны websocket либо Long pool запросы

Comment: понятно, есть ли у вас какие-то доки/гайды/сурсы которые помогут мне реализовать это?буду благодарен за любую информацию)

Comment: думаю Ratchet мне поможет.

Answer (score 0):

По ресту так реализовать неполучится, используйте websocket.

Comment: получится, но сложно